# Log file for wi-fi connections

Tags: wifi, wireless, wireless-adapter, captive-portal

I've set up my Pi as a WAP and captive portal (nodogsplash and hostapd). I need to log connections to it in a log file ideally in JSON or XML. The log file needs to contain the date and time of connection, MAC address and hostname.

Is this information logged anywhere, please?

Comment: I'm sure it is, but where probably depends on which captive portal / WAP management software you're running.  Can you please include that detail?

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm running nodogsplash as the captive portal and hostapd for the WAP